# Will GPO setting registry keys be reapplied on reboot?

Tags: active-directory, registry, gpo, registrykey

Most GPO settings are either enforced/user can't change the setting/ or applied only one time /software install/. My question is - if I set a specific registry key using a GPO and the registry key is changed, will the GPO overwrite the registry key with the one set in GPO?
We run a specific software, which sets several registry keys in HKLM\Software. We never had any troubles with computers running Windows7, Vista or etc. The problem is that Windows10 for some reason deletes one of these keys every time when it updates.
I am asking specifically about registry settings, applied to computers in Active Directory via GPO.
Because if the Computer GPO will not override the settings on reboot after they are deleted by Windows10, I would be forced to deploy startup script instead, which will use REG QUERY to check if the key exists and then if it exists - REG DELETE and REG ADD. And if the key does not exist at all - REG ADD to add the key. I want to protect specific registry settings, which Windows10 continues to delete on every update.

Answer (score 0):

Is the program changing the registry or is your startup script? It is best to use group policy instead of startup scripts. You will enjoy more reliability, consistency, and security.

Anyways, on to your question. Yes, GPOs *refresh* every 90 minutes, on reboot, and upon receiving a `gpupdate /force`. Refresh means that the GPO "runs" completing all of the items in the object. For example, let's say you have a key that removes the sign out button in the start menu. Normally when you login you can assume that the sign out button will not appear, but what if you manually added the button using regedit? Would the button reappear next time the computer reboots? It depends on how the GPO is configured. When you add a new 'Registry Item' you have to select one of four actions: Create, Replace, Update, and Delete. If you want to learn more about these here is a [good article](https://www.itpromentor.com/gp-crud/). For brevity, I will say you would most likely want to use 'Replace' as it will replace the key with whatever was in the GPO and will create it if it doesn't exist.

Note that GPOs are refreshed but do not necessarily take effect immediately. Certain GPOs require a restart, logout/login, or closing and reopening a program.

Comment: The program is not changing this registry entry. This specific registry entry sets some management settings for the program, which normal users cannot alter. Previously, there were only a few computers that used the program and the settings were set manually by admin. The problem was that Windows10 deleted the settings after every single update. Now the program is deployed in the network and many computers use it. So, I set the settings using GPO. Because of this known bug, where Windows10 deletes the settings after update, I want both to set and protect these registry keys from any tampering

Comment: @btzom So currently you have the GPO setting a registry key, but it changes when the computer is updated? If that's the case, can you tell me what the permissions are for the key in regedit?

Comment: Previously, the settings were manually set by admin. Now I have GPO to set the keys. What I am asking is whether GPO with action Replace registry key will replace it on every computer reboot, even if Windows10 updates and deletes the key.

Comment: I havent cheched the permissions of this specific key. Will check them and then will report.

Comment: Yes the 'Replace' action will replace it on every reboot. If it does not then something else is running that changes the key (like an old startup script or an interfering GPO). Windows updates may change it, but GPOs will always override those updates (sometimes it takes a reboot before it overrides).

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Even if I delete the key, it's back on the next reboot. Maybe action Update is better, because if nothing changed, it will not rewrite it, but I prefer Replace.

Comment: This may be an issue related to Windows 10 v2004. Can you verify what version of Windows is running on your machines? Consider testing this on v1909 or v20H2.

Comment: I can confirm this issue with both 1909 and 2004. Still haven't tested 20H2. I consider Win10 OS not ready for market. Because of the printing issues, these issues and numerous other issues we have downgraded many of our computers to Win7, when it was still supported. I was forced to deploy GPO, which disabled Updates on Win10 machines and update them via other means. Our sort of work can't afford random updates in any time.

Comment: v20H2 may fix some of these issues for you. It is worth a test attempt. If native means won’t work, then a script is the next best thing (albeit not preferable).